# Get decimal value of Unicode Character C++

Tags: c++

How do I get the decimal values of Unicode Character such as "Ồ"

```
std::string a = "Ồ";
unsigned char c = a[0];
long val = long(c);
cout << val << endl;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
7,891;
```

Comment: What do you think the answer should be? I'm not too familiar with unicode.

Comment: Also, [cannot reproduce](https://onlinegdb.com/rJwa-xN9H). What platform are you on?

Comment: I think the output they show is their _expected_ output, not the actual.  They need to look up a reference for UTF-8.  The encoded character's bytes must be parsed out either manually, or preferably by using tools from the Unicode header.

Comment: @paddy good point. So the better question for the OP I guess is what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal value"? Do you want code points or code units?

Comment: @Chipster I'm on Window.

Comment: @NicolBolas https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1ed3/index.htm. The link show the decimal value in UTF16 that is what I want.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm you can't (easily) store a UTF-16 string into a `std::string`, you need `std::wstring` (or `std::u16string`) for that, eg: `std::wstring a = L"Ồ";` then the rest of the code you showed would make more sense, but would be incomplete for any Unicode codepoints outside the BMP plane (> U+FFFF)

Comment: It shows `7891`(10), and you are getting `7,891`, which is just the result of locale formatting, which you can turn off.

Comment: Also, what you have in your code is an uppercase Ồ, that has a decimal value of 7890. The lowercase ồ would be 7891.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question may look pretty straight-forward but as we delve into it, we'll find it isn't as simple as it might first appear.

The first problem is that `std::string` is defined as `std::basic_string<char>` which isn't really compatible with "Ồ".  Thus the results you get from your code will probably depend on the compiler you use and/or the environment and OS you are running on.  For example, my copy of Visual Studio treats "Ồ" as an invalid ASCII character and puts "?" (or 0x3F) in `a[0]'.

The second problem is that the character "Ồ" is more than eight bits wide, so it may not fit into the variable `c`.  Whatever the compiler put into `a[0]`, the variable `c` will only hold `char` bits of that value.  Again, the results you get are likely to change depending on the compiler you use and/or the environment you run in.

Leaving that aside, let's start by assuming the character "Ồ" is [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND GRAVE (0x1ED2)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1ed2/index.htm).  With that assumption, one might imagine that the answer we are seeking to get is 0x1ED2 right?  But not necessarily.

There are several ways to encode a Unicode character.  The [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) encoding is 0x1ED2 (or 0x00001ED2 if we include all the leading zeros to get thirty-two bits).  The [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding is 0xE1BB92.

So the decimal value of "Ồ" is 7,890 if it is encoded in UTF-32 or 14,793,618 if it is encoded in UTF-8 (I'm ignoring the effects of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) to keep things simple)

The Unicode site has a [FAQ](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) on encodings and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings) has a page too.

As you can see, the answer to your question (to some extent) depends on the encoding you want to use.  One C++ way to deal with encodings is [std::codecvt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt).  Another solution is to just treat your string as a sequence of bytes - which your code attempts to do - but that rather depends on you knowing how your system encodes strings, what endianness you are dealing with, etc.  And the code won't necessarily be portable.

Another wrinkle to consider is that - in the general case - "Ồ" might not be one character.  Obviously it is one character in your code.  But if you read a string in from a disk file say and when printed or displayed that file produces "Ồ" we can't assume the file contains a single "Ồ" character.

Unicode defines [COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT (0x0302)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0302/index.htm) and [COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (0x0300)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0300/index.htm) as separate characters which can be combined with other characters.  And it defines intermediate characters like [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH GRAVE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d2/index.htm) and [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH ACUTE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d3/index.htm) so there are actually several ways you can create a string in memory (or in a disk file) that would give you the same effect as the character "Ồ".

Comment: In my language "Ồ" is a character but after looking at your answer I think you're right. "Ồ" is not a single character but instead of 3 characters. So what I'm trying to do right now is to give the Hex value of "Ồ" character.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm: It *could* be three "characters", depend on how someone chooses to define it. With combining characters, it could be the base character + 2 combining characters. Or it could be the unified version.

Comment: @NicolBolas So do you have any way to convert a UTF16 String to Hex??

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm: Not until you can explain what *exactly* you mean by that. Do you know the difference between a code point and a code unit? If so, which one do you want? Also, numbers are *numbers*; they are not in "hex" or "binary" or "decimal". They're just numbers. You can *represent* a number textually as "hex" or whatever, but that's a matter of how you convert it to a string.

Comment: "In the Java SE API documentation, Unicode code point is used for character values in the range between U+0000 and U+10FFFF, and Unicode code unit is used for 16-bit char values that are code units of the UTF-16 encoding" - Following this I guess what I want is to convert a string to it code unit.